# Get stored procedure parameters' type

Tags: stored-procedures, types, firebird

I need to read the stored procedures' parameters type in Firebird database.

I'm able to read their name, if they are input or output parameters, but where can I get their type? Or how do you solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the combination of the `RDB$PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS` and `RDB$FIELDS` views, as shown below:

```
SELECT rdb$procedure_name, rdb$procedure_parameters.rdb$parameter_name, 
    rdb$fields.rdb$field_name, rdb$fields.rdb$field_type 
FROM rdb$procedure_parameters, rdb$fields 
WHERE rdb$fields.rdb$field_name = rdb$procedure_parameters.rdb$field_source
```

The field type values in RDB$FIELDS are defined as follows:

```
BLOB - 261
CHAR - 14
CSTRING - 40
D_FLOAT - 11
DOUBLE - 27
FLOAT - 10
INT64 - 16
INTEGER - 8
QUAD - 9
SMALLINT - 7
DATE - 12
TIME - 13
TIMESTAMP - 35
VARCHAR - 37
```

See the Interbase Language Reference for more info on these type definitions.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT rdb$procedure_name, 
       rdb$procedure_parameters.rdb$parameter_name, 
       rdb$fields.rdb$field_name, 
       rdb$fields.rdb$field_type, 
       CASE rdb$fields.RDB$FIELD_TYPE 
           WHEN 7 THEN 'SMALLINT' 
           WHEN 8 THEN 'integer' 
           WHEN 9 THEN 'QUAD' 
           WHEN 10 THEN 'FLOAT' 
           WHEN 11 THEN 'D_FLOAT' 
           WHEN 12 THEN 'DATE' 
           WHEN 13 THEN 'TIME' 
           WHEN 14 THEN 'CHAR' 
           WHEN 16 THEN 'INT64' 
           WHEN 27 THEN 'DOUBLE' 
           WHEN 35 THEN 'TIMESTAMP' 
           WHEN 37 THEN 'VARCHAR' 
           WHEN 40 THEN 'CSTRING' 
           WHEN 261 THEN 'BLOB' 
       END AS FIELD_TYPE 
FROM rdb$procedure_parameters, 
     rdb$fields 
WHERE rdb$fields.rdb$field_name = rdb$procedure_parameters.rdb$field_source
```